# ack command line ack-set doesn't seem to work

Tags: grep, ack

I'm trying to search systemd .service files but ack can't seem to find anything. I tried these options to no avail:

```
ack --type-set sysd=.service --sysd MAINPID
ack --all MAINPID
ack --unrestricted MAINPID
```

When using `type-set` ack reckognises the new type:

```
# ack -type-set sysd=.service --help types | grep sysd
--[no]sysd         .service
```

Using grep instead of ack finds what I'm looking for, but why isn't ack able to?

```
# grep MAINPID -R .
./multi-user.target.wants/vixie-cron.service:ExecStop=/bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID
...
```

ack version used is 1.96.

Answer (score 0):

If `ack --unrestricted` can't find it, then something's wrong with how you're invoking it, because `ack -u` is effectively `grep`.

`ack` is designed explicitly for searching source code, not as a general-purpose `grep` replacement.  It looks to me that you're not actually searching source code.  I would suggest that you use `grep` for tasks that are not searching source code.